# Is "knob" associated with penis?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I'm working on something where I used the word knob for a button to drag.

I thought this is the right word.

Then today an english friend of mine told me that knob means penis in english.

This would be very embarrassing when this is the first association you read the sentence.

It is "Drag knob to change the position"

Is it really that bad?

Comment: [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Knob) can help with slang.

Comment: There you can read that it is associated with it. But I want to know if this is the first thing you get in mind or if it is ok to use

Comment: How far one should go in making allowances for other people's hangups is both context-dependent and subjective.

Comment: Why can't you call it a button, or an icon? I don't think I've ever heard the instructions to drag a knob. There are zillions of euphemisms for sexual genitals, someone somewhere will see something naughty in the most innocuous word. A *door knob* is perfectly fine IMO, as is a knob of butter, but now I can't help myself smiling.  :)

Comment: It really depends on what the full context is.  Some people have dirtier minds than others.

Comment: Yes of course but in my mother tongue German there are words which you just wouldn't use because most of the people will associate it with something different which would make it sound ridiculous. Is this the case for knob?

Comment: I have never seen "knob" used for a two-dimensional feature, so besides its sexual association, it seems inappropriate to me to describe something you do on-screen (which I assume is what you're describing).

Comment: If you would write a story with a sexual topic your friend's association of knob connected with penis might have some logic but if you describe a procedure on the computer screen such an association is nonsense. But, as already said above, I find "knob" a very queer word for the thing you have in mind. In the meantime there are standard terms for the area you can click on or drag to another place.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is entirely a matter of opinion whether one sees an unintended anatomical reference in words/names such as *cock, knob, Dick, Willie, Percy* etc.

Comment: You don't **drag** knobs or buttons.  You twist one, press the other. This UI is pretty unintuitive.

Answer (score 4):

Knob means "a projecting part, usually rounded, forming the handle of a door, drawer, or the like; a rounded lump or protuberance on the surface or at the end of something, as a knot on a tree trunk". It can be used to mean a handle, or even a button. These are the most common and accepted definitions of "knob".

The usage of it in place of penis is British English slang, and is not the first thing you visualize, as a native of British English. American English speakers are often not familiar with that definition at all, thus won't react unfavorably to that usage.

Comment: As an American, that definition of "knob" is known, although we don't use it very often. It's certainly not the first definition that comes to mind when someone encounters the word.

Comment: +1 but I do think it's use for penis is more common than you suggest, as well as derivatives like 'knobhead' (idiot) and other grosser words.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to find a word that has *not* been given an obscene slang meaning at some time is remarkably difficult. Though most people will know the additional meaning of 'knob' only teenagers will snigger over it.